# Is there a use for XAML <ColumnDefinition>Something Here Example</ColumnDefinition>?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml

I was just creating a Grid in my XAML when i noticed that Visual Studio automatically creates ColumnDefinitions like this:

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
      <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

I always stop this from happening by using the shorthand  but then wondered would there be any purpose for using the long hand equivalent; can you put anything in between these tags?

Thanks,
Kohan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you *could* specify sub-properties using property element syntax, but I have no idea why you would:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition.Width>
                Auto
            </ColumnDefinition.Width>
        </ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBlock>Hi</TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you wanted to use an attached property:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition>
            <mystuff:Adorners.Overlay>
                <TextBlock>I'm on top of the column!</TextBlock>
            <mystuff:Adorners.Overlay>
        </ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBlock>Hi</TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

I haven't actually tried this it seems like it should work if you co a use case for it.